# SSLv3 Error in Woocommerce with Paypal Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress/Woocommerce site running on a Windows 2012 R2 Server with IIS 7. Woocommerce is talking to paypal sandbox. Since I while the IPN does not work anymore. I am sure it has to do with the security issues with SSL3.

The error I am getting is:

SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I tried to disable SSL3 on the server. As far as I read TLS 1.2 should be automatically enabled on Windows 2012. Not sure why it is still getting the sslv3 error ? Currently running php5.4 but tried to run it with php7. Same issue.

Not sure what I need to do next to over come this problem ?

Anyone any suggestions ?

thanks a lot in advance.
Moz

Comment: If you are getting this error it means you are not sending the request via TLS 1.2, so there must be something about the server that needs to be configured differently to make it do that.  I'm not familiar with figuring that out in IIS, but I'm sure Google can get you there.

Comment: The "SSL23" may be a red herring. OpenSSL used to name all of its functions "SSL23" and "SSLv3" even when they had nothing to do with SSLv3. Many will point out [it causes a great deal of confusion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mailing.openssl.users/FW6DR--s7ho/XaKvsFMlMGoJ). The [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSLv23_server_method.html) points out that despite the name, they support all versions of TLS.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. One thing I am not clear. Paypal is sending an IPN to my IIS server. The log shows that the IPN data comes in but then this error happens. Is the flow that paypal reaches the IIS but then the IIS tries to respond to paypal and that's when the error happens ? Any ideas ? IF that's the case the to your point Andrew I would need to figure out how to tell IIS to send TLS 1.2 ?